# OpenGL gives exception when using dll made using it

Tags: c, exception, opengl, dll

I am making a library in C using OpenGL. It does nothing but creates a window, but when I use it on a sample program, it always crashes and gives the exception:--

'Exception thrown: write access violation'

'"win" was nullptr'

But when I use it as a header and link it directly to the sample program without any external linkage, it works, unusually. Is it something that I missed that OpenGL does not allow me to make any libraries and dlls with it. I am trying to make my own framework with it.

I am using GLFW and GLEW too.

### **Edit:**

**window.c:**

```
#include "window.h"
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Create the structures... */

struct LIB_Vector2i
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct LIB_Vector2f
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct LIB_Window
{
    LIB_String title;
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    LIB_Bool fullscreen;
    GLFWwindow* window;
};

/* Start the functions here... */
LIB_Bool LIB_Initialize()
{
    return (LIB_Bool)glfwInit();
}

void LIB_SetEvents()
{
    glfwPollEvents();
}

void LIB_ClearToColor(LIB_Color color)
{
    glClearColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void LIB_SetFrameColor(LIB_Color color)
{
    glClearColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
}

LIB_Window* LIB_CreateWindow(const LIB_String title, int x, int y, int width, int height, const LIB_Bool resizable, const LIB_Bool fullscreen)
{
    LIB_Window wind;
    wind.title = title;
    wind.x = x;
    wind.y = y;
    wind.width = width;
    wind.height = height;
    wind.fullscreen = fullscreen;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, resizable);

    GLFWwindow* window = NULL;
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        if (fullscreen == 1)
        {
            window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
        }
        else if (fullscreen == 0)
        {
            window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }

    int screen_width, screen_height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screen_width, &screen_height);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    return &wind;
}

void LIB_GetCenterPosition(LIB_Window * window, int *x, int *y)
{
    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    *x = (mode->width - window->width) / 2;
    *x = (mode->height - window->height) / 2;
}

void LIB_GetWindowFrameSize(LIB_Window * window, int *width, int *height)
{
    int screenwidth, screenheight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window->window, &screenwidth, &screenheight);
    *width = screenwidth;
    *height = screenheight;
}

void LIB_GetWindowCursorPosition(LIB_Window * window, float *x, float *y)
{
    double cx, cy;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window->window, &cx, &cy);
    *x = (float)cx;
    *y = (float)cy;
}

void LIB_GetDisplaySize(int *width, int *height)
{
    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    *width = mode->width;
    *height = mode->height;
}

void LIB_GetWindowPosition(LIB_Window * window, int *x, int *y)
{
    *x = window->x;
    *y=  window->y;
}

void LIB_GetWindowSize(LIB_Window * window, int *width, int *height)
{
    *width = window->width;
    *height = window->height;
}

LIB_String LIB_GetWindowTitle(LIB_Window * window)
{
    return window->title;
}

LIB_Bool LIB_IsWindowFullScreen(LIB_Window * window)
{
    return window->fullscreen;
}

LIB_Bool LIB_IsWindowOpened(LIB_Window * window)
{
    return !glfwWindowShouldClose(window->window);
}

void LIB_SwapWindowBuffers(LIB_Window * window)
{
    glfwSwapBuffers(window->window);
}

void LIB_SetWindowPosition(LIB_Window * window, int x, int y)
{
    glfwSetWindowPos(window->window, x,y);
    window->x = x;
    window->y = y;
}

void LIB_SetWindowSize(LIB_Window * window, int width, int height)
{
    glfwSetWindowSize(window->window, width, height);
    window->width = width;
    window->height = height;
}

void LIB_SetWindowTitle(LIB_Window * window, const LIB_String title)
{
    glfwSetWindowTitle(window->window, title);
    window->title = title;
}

void LIB_SetFullScreenState(LIB_Window * window, const LIB_Bool fullscreen)
{
    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    if (fullscreen == LIB_FALSE)
    {
        glfwSetWindowMonitor(window->window, NULL, window->x, window->y, window->width, window->height, 60);
    }
    else if (fullscreen == LIB_TRUE)
    {
        glfwSetWindowMonitor(window->window, glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), 0, 0, mode->width, mode->height, 60);
    }
    window->fullscreen = fullscreen;
}

void LIB_DestroyWindow(LIB_Window * window)
{
    window->title = NULL;
    window->x = 0;
    window->y = 0;
    window->width = 0;
    window->height = 0;
    free(window);
}

void LIB_Terminate()
{
    printf("LIB terminated by the user!!\n");
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

**window.h:**

```
#ifndef LIB_GRAPHICS
#define LIB_GRAPHICS

#define LIB_FALSE 0
#define LIB_TRUE 1

#define LIB_BeginRender LIB_SetEvents(); LIB_ClearToColor
#define LIB_EndRender LIB_SwapWindowBuffers

/* Define other things... */

typedef const char* LIB_String;
typedef unsigned LIB_Integer;
typedef char LIB_Char;
typedef int LIB_Bool;

/* Define the structures... */

typedef struct LIB_Window LIB_Window;

typedef struct LIB_Color
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    int a;
} LIB_Color;

#ifndef LIB_EXPORTS
#define LIB_EXPORTS _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIB_EXPORTS _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

/* Constructors, destructors and other functions... */

LIB_EXPORTS LIB_Bool LIB_Initialize();
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_SetEvents();
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_ClearToColor(LIB_Color color);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_SetFrameColor(LIB_Color color);


LIB_EXPORTS LIB_Window* LIB_CreateWindow(LIB_String title, int x, int y, int width, int height, LIB_Bool resizable, LIB_Bool fullscreen);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_GetDisplaySize(int *width, int *height);

LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_GetCenterPosition(LIB_Window* window, int *x, int *y);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_GetWindowFrameSize(LIB_Window* window, int *width, int *height);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_GetWindowCursorPosition(LIB_Window* window, float *x, float *y);

LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_GetWindowPosition(LIB_Window* window, int *x, int *y);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_GetWindowSize(LIB_Window* window, int *width, int *height);
LIB_EXPORTS LIB_String LIB_GetWindowTitle(LIB_Window* window);
LIB_EXPORTS LIB_Bool LIB_IsWindowFullScreen(LIB_Window* window);
LIB_EXPORTS LIB_Bool LIB_IsWindowOpened(LIB_Window* window);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_SwapWindowBuffers(LIB_Window* window);

LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_SetWindowPosition(LIB_Window* window, int x, int y);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_SetWindowSize(LIB_Window* window, int width, int height);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_SetWindowTitle(LIB_Window* window, LIB_String title);
LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_SetFullScreenState(LIB_Window* window, LIB_Bool fullscreen);

LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_DestroyWindow(LIB_Window* window);


LIB_EXPORTS void LIB_Terminate();

#endif /* LIB_GRAPHICS */
```

Comment: This sounds like something to do with deployment. Have you checked to make sure that application is linked properly (static libraries are included into your exe and dynamic libraries are accessible) at runtime? You will most certainly need platform specific dll's to run the app.

Comment: The other thought I have is that you need to make sure that you are not trying to use the Opengl context from multiple threads without making it current.  Perhaps uploading some relevant code and deployment details.  It's hard to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make the slightest sense. You declare a `struct LIB_Window` with `GLFWwindow*` member, and in `LIB_CreateWindow()`  you create a local `struct LIB_Window` variable where you never assign the actual window to the struct member, and then, you return an *address to the variable on the stack* which becomes invalid the moment the function is left (and some code paths just use `return;` without a value at all.).

This code is just completely broken on the C side, your issues have nothing to do with DLLs or OpenGL.